# Interactive chart in C# - set cursor by mouse-click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I'm new to C# and windowsforms applications. I'm trying to create a, at least to some extend, interactive chart. As of now I have not found a library or a built-in method to do what I have in mind.

I want to be able to:

1. Set a cursor when I click in the chart, set a 2nd cursor when I click again.
2. When 2 cursors are set, I want to be able to move them with the mouse (click to grab).
3. (If possible side by side with cursor click-placing:
   "Zoom the chart by drawing a rectangle in the chart by clicking and moving the mouse".
   My intention is to enable zoom as in: [MS Chart Control: prevent zoom when clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275507/ms-chart-control-prevent-zoom-when-clicking))

I'd like to do this to analyze data (see: [Cursor setting example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQk3M.png)). With the cursors it should be possible to easily get the values of the two cursor positions (yellow and red lines) and to measure the distance in between (purple line).

Does anyone of you know how to do this with a mouse_click event OR know a chart library to easily do that?

Thanks for your help!

-Phill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution to my question and posted it as an answer there: [How to retrieve the selected range in the .Net WinForms Chart Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777087/how-to-retrieve-the-selected-range-in-the-net-winforms-chart-control/60954737#60954737)

To add colored cursors I also add 2 dataseries that are yellow and red to the method `private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)`:

```
chart1.Series["CursorX1"].Points.AddXY(x1,y1Min);`
chart1.Series["CursorX1"].Points.AddXY(x1,y1Max); 
chart1.Series["CursorX1"].Points.Color = Color.Red;

chart1.Series["CursorX2"].Points.AddXY(x2,y2Min);`
chart1.Series["CursorX2"].Points.AddXY(x2,y2Max); 
chart1.Series["CursorX2"].Points.Color = Color.Yellow;
```